# How I can prompt git users to login everytime they push?

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, githooks

we are hosting gitlab on our server with only https authentication. Users can login either through webui or shell. With a web UI everything is working as desired.

The use case is when user is getting authenticated over shell, we trigger our custom server side hooks in order to authorize that user which branch he/she can access to and can do only specified actions there. Therefore we need to prompt users to provide their login/pass everytime they push to the repo.

We have tested a lot of ways, but issue seems to be challenging.

Do you know how can we solve this problem?

Comment: did you try using https url? `https://user@gitlab.com/repo`

Comment: Alejandro, i didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: You should better ask a question how to solve the original problem and not the solution that you think might work. When the user is already authenticated it should not be necessary to re-login again. Especially with username + password when you normally just login with your key. That is not a good usability experience.

Comment: Werner, the problem regarding to the point you mentioned is that if the user is authenticated a month ago and pushes to repo today, we can not match push history with the authenticated user's credential, because we can not get the username of account via each push request. We can get just comitter name, but this might be faked by user. Hence IMHO we should get these 2 - push history and credentials together every time to match and authorize user based on custom rules in hooks.

Comment: Sorry, but looks like you created a non-standard process, and living issues from it. @AlejandroNortes gave a suggestion, which may work or not, but the fact you didnt undestand it, is what worries me more. My suggestion is to step back and re-evaluate the whole process, if possible, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve this issue by getting user-id per each push request within gitlab-shell:

`key_id = ENV.delete('GL_ID') # this retrieves the actual user-id, which might be mapped to the username which differ from author or committer`